# Taking part of text from a variable

Tags: php

I have a PHP variable `$data` that is like:

```
{
    "PlacePrices": [{
        "Id": "JO",
        "Name": "Giordania",
        "DirectPrice": 26,
        "HolidayUrl": null
    }, {
        "Id": "CY",
        "Name": "Cipro",
        "DirectPrice": 86,
        "IndirectPrice": 71,
        "HolidayUrl": null
    }, {
        "Id": "MK",
        "Name": "Macedonia del Nord",
        "DirectPrice": 30,
        "HolidayUrl": null
    }, {
        "Id": "AM",
        "Name": "Armenia",
        "DirectPrice": 75,
        "HolidayUrl": null
    }, {
        "Id": "PL",
        "Name": "Polonia",
        "DirectPrice": 28,
        "HolidayUrl": null
    },
```

I want to take a part of it like:

```
Giordania :26
```

or

```
Cipro : 86
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Use `json_decode($data)`, then you can reference, like, e.g:  `echo $data->PlacePrices[0]->Name; // Giordiana`. If you need to turn the json into an associative array use: `json_decode($data, true);` which would allow you to reference like eg: `echo $data['PlacePrices'][0]['Name']; // Giordiana`

Comment: @jibsteroos i get this errors: 
Notice: Trying to get property 'PlacePrices' of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 13

Notice: Trying to get property 'Name' of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 13

Comment: I formated the JSON, for us to see better assuming that you want to treat it as a JSON string. However, please note that you didn't post the full JSON contents. Your question is unclear as to what you want to do with this variable.

Comment: That is the type of notice you get when the json is **invalid** - I noticed the json in your question is invalid, but assumed it was because you had just cut out a sample. Your json needs to be closed with `]}` and the last comma dropped for it to be valid. Then the referencing will work [demo](https://3v4l.org/ZC28B)